# Errors when installing python-mode using package-install in emacs 23

Tags: emacs

I am running emacs 23 on scientific linux. I'm trying to get python-mode working, but when I try to install it via `package-install [RET] -python-mode` I get a long list of warnings, starting with:

```
Leaving directory `/home/umroot/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode-20150909.2301'

Compiling file /home/umroot/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode-20150909.2301/python-mode.el at Tue Sep 29 11:08:29 2015

Entering directory `/home/umroot/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode-20150909.2301/'
python-mode.el:2315:7:Warning: variable assignment to constant
    `py-block-closing-keywords-re'
```

and ending with

```
In py-complete-initialize:
pycomplete.el:413:9:Warning: reference to free variable
    `py-set-complete-keymap-p'
pycomplete.el:423:11:Warning: assignment to free variable `ac-sources'
pycomplete.el:430:32:Warning: assignment to free variable `company-backends'
pycomplete.el:434:17:Warning: reference to free variable `python-mode-map'

In end of data:
pycomplete.el:437:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined: pymacs-load,
    py-backward-def, py-backward-class, pycomplete-pycompletions,
    pycomplete-pydocstring, pycomplete-pyhelp,
    pycomplete-pysignature, pycomplete-pylocation,
    pycomplete-pyparse
```

I don't know what else might be relevant here. I am using Anaconda for python.

Answer (score 0):

python-mode.el undergoes tests before every commit/upload. No crucial bugs known so far.

Nonetheless will look how the reduce the warnings. In case of

python-mode.el:2315:7:Warning: variable assignment to constant

```
`py-block-closing-keywords-re'
```

for example using "defvar" instead of "defconst" should make it gone.

Thanks reporting.